# Getting the index of first occurrence of fragment from fragment back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

Assume if fragment stack is  like D->C->*A*->B-C->A->B->C->A->B->A , i need to get the position of fragment A which is added to back stack first that is position 2 in my case.

Answer (score 0):

you can find out the potion of fragment by using below code .

```
 FragmentManager frgmanager = getFragmentManager();
    for (int i = 0; i < frgmanager .getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
        if (frgmanager .getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(tagname)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
```

but please insert it to backstack with tag name.

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment, tagname);
 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tagname);
```